# Which is the best DNS Server solution for Windows Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I'd like to move on Windows Server 2008 and could save 20 Euro every month if I am using Web Edition instead of the Standard Edition. The only "problem", Windows Server 2008 hasn't a build in DNS Server anymore.

Now I am asking me, which is the best third party DNS for my Webserver. I took a look on simpleDNS it seems quiet cool. Any additional idea or experience?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like the DNS role is included in Windows Web Server 2008 **R2**.  See http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx

Comment: You're right, did they change the featurelist in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider installing [Bind](https://www.isc.org/software/bind) on the server (some hints [here](http://alex.charrett.com/techstuff/bind9-win2k.html) for getting it up and running) or within a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks BIND is a good idea I found also Tutorials now for Windows Server 2008:

Install:http://windowsserver.trainsignal.com/install-bind-dns-on-windows-web-server-2008

Configure: http://windowsserver.trainsignal.com/configure-bind-dns-on-windows-web-server-2008

Answer (score 2):

Many registrars allow you reasonably complete control of your DNS zone if you leave the DNS management with them instead of pointing the name server records elsewhere. If you are confident of your registrar's DNS arrangements (and don't need extra features they don't generally offer, like short (or control of) TTLs or dynamic DNS updates) this this is a zero-extra-cost solution.

Answer (score 1):

I like the guys over at http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com.  I have been using them a couple of years.  They do a good job, and the price fits my pocketbook.